# How to add user from guest user?

Tags: useradd

I've installed ubuntu using wubi from windows. I remembered I provided an username and password. But now I can log in only as guest user from where I can't privileges to install or run program. Can anyone help me giving solution how to add user from guest user and get root privileges.

I tried to log on in terminal providing my username and password. but this showed incorrect.

Comment: Do you remember the username and password you provided, and it simply won't let you log into the user from the login screen?   Or can you not log in because you forget that information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 1):

If you remember the username and password you set, and it simply won't let you log on to the user but only to the guest account, this is how you can do what you are asking:

Hit Ctrl+Alt+F1

Type in your username (not display name--the username is typically one word with no capitals) and hit Enter

Enter in your password when it asks, and hit Enter

Use the command:

```
sudo adduser newusername
```

Answer the series of questions it asks.  To give that new account administrative privileges, enter into the Terminal:

```
sudo adduser newusername sudo
```